# Upload Image and Information (both) Using AFNetworking 2.0 in Single PHP

Tags: php, ios, afnetworking

I'm trying to upload multiple images(product pics) and information(brand name,price etc) using AFNetworking 2.0.

I did manage to upload images and information using two separate php files
1. upload_product_info.php
2. upload_product_images.php,

first call upload_product_info.php on Success call upload_product_images.php. everything is working fine but i want it using single php file.

I tried single PHP but it partially work and didn't give any error only upload images, product information fields(product brand, name etc) in Database are always blank.I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I'm newbie in php.

here is my iOS code to upload images and information.

```
- (IBAction)uploadProduct:(id)sender {

// for Testing purpose just taken 2 fields.
  NSString *productbrand  = @"xyz";
  NSString *productname   = @"pqr";

  NSDictionary *infoDictionary = @{@"pbrand": productbrand, @"pname": productname};

  __block NSUInteger success = 0;
  __block NSString *message;
  static int count = 1;

// returns array of product images url from temp Directory.
  productImages = [self returnImagesFromTemporaryDirectory];

  AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

  manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializerWithWritingOptions:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted];
  manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];

  [manager POST:@"http://localhost/~abc/Website/uploadProduct.php" parameters:infoDictionary constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData)
  {
    for (NSURL *filePath in productImages)
    {

      CFStringRef pathExtension = (__bridge_retained CFStringRef)[filePath pathExtension];
      CFStringRef type = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, pathExtension, NULL);
      CFRelease(pathExtension);

      NSString *mimeType = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass(type, kUTTagClassMIMEType);
      NSLog(@" Mime Type : %@", mimeType);

      NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"IMG00%i.png",count];
      count++;

      [formData appendPartWithFileURL:filePath name:@"uploaded_file[]" fileName:imageName mimeType:mimeType error:nil];
    }
  }
    success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
   {
     NSDictionary *responseDic = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;

     success = [responseDic[@"success"] integerValue];
     NSLog(@"Success: %ld",(long)success);
     message = responseDic[@"message"];

     if (success == 1)
     {
       UIAlertView *successAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@" Success " message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

       [successAlert show];
     }

   }
    failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
   {
     NSLog(@"Error: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, error);

     UIAlertView *failedAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@" Failed " message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

     [failedAlert show];
  }];
```

here is my PHP for Images+Information upload.

```
   <?php

    header('Content-type: application/json');

    $json = file_get_contents('php://input'); // Catching input
    $value= json_decode($json, true);   // Decode JSON into Dictionary.

    $response = array();

// retrieve values from Dictionary using key.
    $productBrand = $value['pbrand'];
    $productname  = $value['pname'];


    // Database Connection.
    $mysqlserver="localhost";
    $mysqlusername="abc123";
    $mysqlpassword="pqr123";
    $link=mysql_connect($mysqlserver, $mysqlusername, $mysqlpassword) or die ("Error connecting to mysql server: ".mysql_error());

    $dbname = 'myDatabase';    // change this to the name of your database
    mysql_select_db($dbname, $link) or die ("Error selecting specified database on mysql server: ".mysql_error()); 

    // Insert Data into Table.
     $insertQuery = "INSERT INTO user_test (productBrand, productName) VALUES ('$productBrand', '$productname')";

    $result = mysql_query($insertQuery);

    if($result) 
    {
        $count=0;

             foreach ($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'] as $filename) 
            {
                $file_path="uploads/";             

                $tmp=$_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'][$count];

                move_uploaded_file($tmp,$file_path.$filename);         

             $count=$count + 1;
            }

            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["message"] = "Images uploaded Successfully.";
    } 
    else
    {
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "Failed to upload Images";
    }

    echo json_encode($response);

     ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue seems to be on the PHP side
the lines

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input'); // Catching input
$value= json_decode($json, true);   // Decode JSON into Dictionary.
```

do not work. Replacing the above block with this line

```
$value= $_REQUEST;
```

should resolve your issue .

Comment: Thank you wooknight. it resolve my problem, I really appreciate your help.